# Correct XPathExpression for retrieving Nodes in Java?

Tags: java, xpath

I have an XML document that has multiple `hpp:HourlyHistoricalPrice` elements as in the following way:

```html
<?xml version="1.0">
<hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrices xmlns:hhp="urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrices">
  <hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice xmlns:hhp="urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice">
    <hhp:indexId>1025127</hhp:indexId>
    <hhp:resetDate>20161231T000000</hhp:resetDate>
    <hhp:refSource>AIBO</hhp:refSource>
    <hhp:indexLocation/>
    <hhp:price1>50,870000</hhp:price1>
    ...
    <hhp:price48>43,910000</hhp:price48>
  </hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice>
  <hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice xmlns:hhp="urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice">
    <hhp:indexId>1025127</hhp:indexId>
    <hhp:resetDate>20160101T000000</hhp:resetDate>
    <hhp:refSource>AIBO</hhp:refSource>
    <hhp:indexLocation/>
    <hhp:price1>51,870000</hhp:price1>
    ...
    <hhp:price48>49,910000</hhp:price48>
  </hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice>
  <hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice xmlns:hhp="urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice">
    <hhp:indexId>1025127</hhp:indexId>
    <hhp:resetDate>20163112T000000</hhp:resetDate>
    <hhp:refSource>APX</hhp:refSource>
    <hhp:indexLocation/>
    <hhp:price1>63,870000</hhp:price1>
    ...
    <hhp:price48>29,910000</hhp:price48>
  </hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice>  
</hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrices>
```

I want to retrieve only the `hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice` nodes that have a particular value for `hhp:refSource`, e.g. `AIBO`.

I was trying the below XPathExpression but this retrieves nothing.

```html
 XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        
String strExprssion = 
  "/hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrices/hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice[hhp:refSource='AIBO']";
        
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(strExprssion);
        
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(originalXmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        
System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
```

I would be grateful if somebody could provide advise on the correct expression to use.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `//hhp:HourlyHistoricalPrice[hhp:refSource='AIBO']`?

Comment: I have tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the prefix into the xml namespace it represents:

```
String strExprssion = "//urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice:HourlyHistoricalPrice[urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice:refSource='AIBO']";
```

So for me, this test class

```
public class XPathCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

        try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream(Paths.get("src", "inputFile.xml").toFile())) {
            String strExprssion = "//urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice:HourlyHistoricalPrice[urn:or-HourlyHistoricalPrice:refSource='AIBO']";
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(strExprssion);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(new InputSource(file), XPathConstants.NODESET);

            System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
        }
    }
}
```

outputs "2".

Comment: Thanks for your response @daniu, I have tried your suggestion but still did not get anything in the list of nodes.

Comment: I get an output of "2" (ie the nodes list length).